# Mongodb Update Embedded Documents Using Multiple Field Matches with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document structure on mongodb like below:

```
{
    _id: <string>,
    field1: ...,
    field2: ...,
    field3: ...,
    DeviceVersionPairs: [{ 
            DeviceId: <ObjectId>, 
            CloudFolderId: <ObjectId>, 
            CloudFileId: <ObjectId>, 
            VersionId: <ObjectId>, 
            Status: <int>
        },{ 
            DeviceId: <ObjectId>, 
            CloudFolderId: <ObjectId>, 
            CloudFileId: <ObjectId>, 
            VersionId: <ObjectId>, 
            Status: <int>
        }, 
        ....
    ]
}
```

I wrote this mongodb query, it is designed to find the row with the `_id` given than update the subdocument in its `DeviceVersionPairs` array matching the `elemMatch` filter, which actually works;

```
db.deduplications.update({
    "_id": "...", 
    "DeviceVersionPairs": { "$elemMatch" : {
        "DeviceId": ObjectId("..."), 
        "CloudFolderId": ObjectId("..."), 
        "CloudFileId": ObjectId("..."), 
        "VersionId": ObjectId("...")
    }}
},{
    "$set": { "DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status": 100 }
}, false, false)
```

But I can't convert it to use with C# driver(2.0.1.27). So far I had this, but this lacks the `elemMatch` statement, hence it doesn't work as expected.

```
var p = DbContext.Deduplications.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
    filter: Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("_id", fileHash),
        Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId", deviceId),
        Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId", CloudFolderId),
        Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId", FileId),
        Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId", versionIdToBeRemoved)),
    update: Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Update.Set("DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status", DVPStatus.PassiveOrDeleted)).Result;
```

What is the way to make such a request to mongodb using C# driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've come up with my own solution. Creating the filter using the regular `BsonDocument` objects did the job.

```
var filter = new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement> {
    new BsonElement("_id", fileHash),
    new BsonElement("DeviceVersionPairs", new BsonDocument("$elemMatch", new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement> {
        new BsonElement("DeviceId", deviceId),
        new BsonElement("CloudFolderId", cloudFolderId),
        new BsonElement("CloudFileId", cloudFileId),
        new BsonElement("VersionId", versionId)
    })))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match on any element inside the array? If  so this should work:

```
var p = DbContext.Deduplications.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
filter: Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.AnyEq(
    Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("_id", fileHash),
    Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId", deviceId),
    Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId", CloudFolderId),
    Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId", FileId),
    Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Filter.Eq("DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId", versionIdToBeRemoved)),
update: Builders<Dal.Deduplication>.Update.Set("DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status", DVPStatus.PassiveOrDeleted)).Result;
```

Comment: if all of the fields match than I will update it's status. Actually there will only be single element in array. I should try this.

Comment: `AnyEq` does not except these 5 parameters.

Comment: any suggestions?